# iOS SpriteKit: move node in correct direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

In mastering iOS and SpriteKit I'm working on a game using Objective-C. It is basically a top-down driving game with a button for speed and two direction buttons for left and right.
However I can't seem to figure out how to properly get the steering working.

So far, I've implemented the three buttons, which make a node (the car) move forward and also turn to an angle to a certain amount. The concerning code looks like this:

```
#define SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 0.01745329252f)
#define SK_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 57.29577951f)

@implementation GameScene {

    SKSpriteNode *car;

    int speed;
    int rotation; 

    BOOL turnRight;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    // Drive button
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"driveNode"]) {

        speed = 120;
    }


    // Right
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"moveRight"]) {

        turnRight = YES;
        rotation = rotation + 20;
    }


    // Left
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"moveLeft"]) {

        rotation = rotation - 20;
    }
}
```

And for updating:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

if (turnRight == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Turning right..");

    /*
    I imagine that calculations should be done here
    */

    }

    float angle = atan2f(speed, rotation);
    car.zRotation = angle - SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90);

    CGFloat rate = 1;
    CGVector relativeVelocity = CGVectorMake(rotation, speed - car.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
    car.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(rotation, car.physicsBody.velocity.dy + relativeVelocity.dy * rate);
}
```

I set the value of `turnRight` to NO in `touchesEnded`

My problem is that in the way this is implemented now the car can't turn more to the right than horizontally. What I want is when the right button is continued to be pressed, the car should eventually drive in a circle at a constant speed. I can't figure out the logic and math how to implement this.

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775146/spritekit-rotate-a-node-while-touching) among others, which helped me in some way, but I have not figured it out completely yet.

Can anyone put me in the right direction here? I've looked around the web and stack for solutions, but have not found any that can help me out.

Comment: Those look like global variables?

Comment: Yes, i've implemented them under @implementation

Comment: They still sound like global variables unless they are within the initial declaration section (i.e. `{` and `}`).

Comment: I've updated the code above, did you mean that?

Comment: Yes; now they are (private) instance variables which is correct.

Comment: Your post title says _move node in correct direction_, but you are actually asking the game control (left/right button), the mechanics (car motion) and even the logic. Try to separate these questions and let people help you in a [more clear and specific way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts/39224#39224).

Comment: @WangYudong thanks, i've tried to make my problem more clear and simple

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: if I release the touch, the car should continue to drive in a direct line?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check apply torque.  It will not adjust the speed of your car.

> - applyTorque: Applies a torque to an object.
>
> Declaration SWIFT func applyTorque(_ torque: CGFloat) OBJECTIVE-C
>   - (void)applyTorque:(CGFloat)torque Parameters torque  The amount of torque, in Newton-meters. Discussion This method generates an angular
>   acceleration on the body without causing any linear acceleration. The
>   force is applied for a single simulation step (one frame).
>
> Availability Available in iOS 7.0 and later. See Also – applyForce: –
>   applyForce:atPoint: mass